# Remote Connection to SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017

I have just created a new SQL Server with SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000) and SSIS (14.0). I am able to remote connect with the admin user on that server whom I did all of the setup/configuration with, however my client is not able to. I went in to dcomcnfg and explicitly gave their user all of the necessary permissions, still they are unable to connect. I've already verified that we are using the correct version of SSMS (17.X) but I've also tried with SSMS 18 and 15 to no avail.

When trying to make the connection from a remote desktop the error message goes something like "The specified service does not exist as an installed service".
I've given the user sa credentials in SQL and full permission through DCOM for SSIS.

I am relatively new to this so it is possible I completely missed an obvious step here and I'd love some input on this, thank you.

Comment: What error are they getting? What permissions does the user have in SQL and SSIS?